# Query where multiple elements of same name exist List

Tags: c#, linq, list

Windows form app

Okay sorry I have a class

```
public class comm
   {

      private int dayV;
      private string timeV;
      private decimal priceV;
      private string nameValue;
      private string descriptionV;

      public comm(string Day, string Time, string Price, string Name, string Description)
      {
         try
         {
            this.dayV = Convert.ToInt32(Day);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {

         }

         this.timeV = Time;
         decimal PriceVal;
         var irishCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-IE");
         if (decimal.TryParse(Price, NumberStyles.Currency, irishCulture, out PriceVal))
         {
            this.priceV = Convert.ToDecimal(PriceVal);
         }
         this.nameValue = Name;
         this.descriptionV = Description;
      }


      public int GetDay() { return dayV; }
      public string GetTime() { return timeV; }
      public string GetPrice() { return (Convert.ToString(priceV)); }
      public string GetName() { return nameValue; }

      // Returns full event Description
      public string Description()
      {
         string price = "Price: ";
         return timeV + "\r\n" + price + "€" + priceV + "\r\n" + this.descriptionV;
      }
   }
```

I read the text file into a List and assign each field into the corresponding class instance variable.

Text file looks like this

```
1,02:29 pm,€55.00,John D,Main st 
1,05:43 pm,€70.00,John D,Bridge st
2,01:43 pm,€100.00,Mike O,First Floor A12
1,10:44 am,€100.00,Colm Collins,First Floor A13
2,11:44 am,€110.00,Martin O, Exp 01
```

The method that reads the file.

```
    public List<communityEvent> CreateList()
          {
             List<comm> entries = new List<comm>();
             try
             {
                StreamReader fileIn = new StreamReader(path);
                //Read the file
                while (!fileIn.EndOfStream)
                {
                   String line = fileIn.ReadLine();
                   String[] pieces = line.Split(',');
                   if (pieces.Length == 5)
                   {
                      comm Eve = new comm(pieces[0], pieces[1], pieces[2], pieces[3], pieces[4]);
                      entries.Add(Eve);
                   }
        return entries;
```

In the main program

```
    private List<comm> various;



    private void ExtractData(string eventComboBox)
{
    var query = from v in various
                     where vComboBox == v.GetName()
                     select v.Description();

         foreach (var vr in query)
         {
            descriptionTextBox.Text = vr;
         }
}
```

So the combobox contents would look like this:-

```
             John D
             John D
             Colm Collins
             Martin O
```

What I would like is, each time the user selects a different name.
I get the corresponding description() eg. the first John D when selected will populate the description textbox with Description() which should be the fields from that line.
The problem I am having is, some names are the same the description only returns the first description()for all the people who have the same name regardless of which one I select.

Comment: Your question is rather ambiguous.

Comment: If it's a WPF app, you should bind the `SelectedItem` property of the combo box to a `SelectedItem` property in your view model and then bind the `descriptionTextBox.Text` to the Description of the SelectedItem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the added information. It's still vague – I don't know what "the individual description" means, since you wrote, and your new example of the data shows, that there can be more than one match in the data. There is no "*the* individual description" when you select a name that matches multiple names.

That said, if you only want one description then it seems that what you really want is to correlate the *single* item in the `ComboBox` with the *single* item in your data from which the `ComboBox` was populated.

Unfortunately, you still have not provided a complete code example as requested. So there's no way to know how the `ComboBox` is populated or even how the `various` variable is declared. But you said the data is read "into a List", so let's assume:

- You have some type `DataRow` that represents a single line of text in your file
- `various` is declared as a `List<DataRow>`
- The order of the items in the `ComboBox` is exactly the same as the order of the items in the `various` list

If the above is all true (and without a complete code example, it's not possible for anyone reading your question to know for sure it is), then you don't need or want to query the data at all. *You already know the exact index of the item that was selected!*

Let us further assume that:

- The name of your `ComboBox` is "comboBox1" and you have a field in your code named `comboBox1` that refers to that `ComboBox` instance

In that case, the following code should suffice as a replacement for the entire code example you provided:

```
descriptionTextBox.Text = various[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].Description();
```

This retrieves the index of the current selection in the `ComboBox`, and then uses that index (since the order of the data in the `ComboBox` should be exactly the same as in the `List<DataRow>`) to retrieve the `DataRow` value from the `List<DataRow>`, for the purpose of calling the `Description()` method to get the actual description for that row of data and assigning it to your `descriptionTextBox`'s `Text` property.

If your `ComboBox` has a different name, simply use the correct name instead of `comboBox1` in the above.

Again, if that doesn't address your question, please add detail to the question. Provide a minimal, ***complete*** code example, and explain exactly what it does and how that's different from what you wanted to happen.

Comment: Thanks, no, I'm trying to get the individual description each time combobox selection changes. sorry about my question being badly written

Comment: @Tom: Your question should still have a _complete_ code example. But please see the above revised answer in case it addresses your question.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
descriptionTextBox.Text = various[comboBox.SelectedIndex].Description();
```

Comment: Could you please edit in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are discouraged, because they harder for people to learn the reasons behind the problem.

Comment: Sorry I Get. Error 1 'string' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedIndex' and no extension method 'SelectedIndex' accepting a first argument

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help, the following is what worked for me
I created a method and fed the combo box text and index into it.

```
    private void ExtractData(string eventComboBo, int index)
  {

     var query = from v in various
                 where eventComboBo == v.GetName() && eventComboBox.SelectedIndex.Equals(index)
                 select v.Description();

     foreach (var ev in query)
     {
        descriptionTextBox.Text = ev;
     }
```